# Targeting an individual iframe with CSS

Tags: html, css, iframe

On my tumblr blog here: http://ukgraffiti.tumblr.com/ I've used:

```
iframe {opacity:0}
iframe:hover {opacity:1}
```

to hide the tumblr control buttons (Follow, Dashboard) so that they only show up when a user hovers over them.

Unfortunately other elements get affected in the same way. If, for instance, I post a song to my blog, the little player widget is hidden in the same way. Also, posts can be opened for answers, which results in a little answer form below the post. This is also affected by the ifram opacity setting.

Would it be possible to target ONLY the tumblr buttons with the opacity ruling?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case any fellow tumblr users are interested, the answer is:

```
.tmblr-iframe:nth-of-type(1) { opacity:0; }
.tmblr-iframe:hover { opacity:1 !important; }
```

Thanks to all who tried to help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to all of the iframes you want to have the opacity rule and then target that class with your CSS.

Ex. HTML:

```
<iframe class="className"></iframe>
```

Ex. CSS:

```
iframe.className {opacity:0}
iframe.className:hover {opacity:1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm not brilliant at coding, so can you just clarify where that class goes. I only want to target the tumblr buttons in the top right corner, but I'm not sure where I need to put that className. Can it just go anywhere in my html or does it have to wrap around the html for the buttons? Problem is, I have no idea what part of the html controls the buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure I can. I've searched through the whole code for 'iframe' and the only ones it finds are the CSS ones for opacity that I added. I think these things are controlled by tumblr, but I thought because I was able to target them with CSS, I could target them individually.

Comment: I found this while searching the net for an answer. Not sure if it's what you need. `code`<iframe scrolling=”no” frameborder=”0” id=”tumblr_controls” src=”http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?10&src=http%3A%2F`%2F{Title}.tumblr.com%2F{block:PermalinkPage}post%2f{PostID}{/block:PermalinkPage}{block:IndexPage}page%2F{CurrentPage}{/block:IndexPage}&{block:PermalinkPage}pid={PostID}{/block:PermalinkPage}&rk=bgGiB47i&lang=en_US&name={Title}” style=”position: fixed;z-index:1337;top:0px;right:0px;border:0px;background-color:transparent;overflow:hidden;width: 330px;height: 25px;”></iframe>`code`

Comment: Sorry, but unless you can edit the HTML and CSS of the page you are unable to do this.

Comment: I can edit the HTML and CSS of the page, but the code for the iframe is not part of it. Maybe this is the problem, but I thought because I could hide the iframe elements with CSS, I would be able to target each element individually. Maybe not. Anyway, thanks very much for all your help.